# Javascript: Getting node value

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to Javascript and I need to get the value of the node with id `firstvalue` so that I can use it in my script. Can anyone please tell me how do I get that value?

```
<div id="myDiv">

<span id="firstValue"> 5.22 <span id="nestedValue"> 500 </span></span>

</div> <!-- myDiv -->
```

Comment: Do you want the inner html (it is nested) or the first value, that would be something like the text content. If the latter, what should be retrieved in the case `<span id="firstValue"> 5.22 <span> foo</span> 42 </span>`?

Comment: @Dilettant: I want to retrieve just 5.22 and ignore everything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.getElementById("firstValue")` will get you a reference to the `<span>`. This has two child nodes, which you can reference via the array-like [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.childNodes) property, or in this case simply using `firstChild` and `lastChild` properties. For example, the following will return you the string " 5.22 ":

```
document.getElementById("firstValue").firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: So I can go down the tree using `firstChild` (or more generally `childNodes[i]`) and get whatever value I need, thank you I was going to get a lot confused and you spared me a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 2):

```
var nodeValue = document.getElementById("firstValue").innerHTML
```

this will = "`5.22 <span id="nestedValue"> 500 </span>`"

Comment: so there's no way to catch that value only?

Comment: I'd make it easy on myself and not nest the two items.

Answer (score 1):

Many javascript libraries are helping a lot in accessing DOM elements, such as: prototype, dojo, jQuery to name a few. In prototype you would type: `$('firstValue').firstChild.nodeValue`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function for that purpose, and with error handling for the case the span would not exist or would be empty:

```
function getFirstValue() {
    var spanFirstValue = document.getElementById("firstValue");
    if (spanFirstValue) {
        var textNode = spanFirstValue.childnodes[0];
        if (textNode) {
            return textNode.data;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done like so...

```
document.getElementById("firstValue").textContent;
```

Which will give you the text content without the html.