# Add two numbers and display result in textbox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, textbox

I was just trying to write a simple javascript program that will demonstrate to take user input from text field, and clicking the button will display the summation result of those number in another text field. But unfortunately the below code is not working. Clicking the button does not show anything in the result text field.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h1>Add two number using text box as input using javascript</h1>
        </div>
            Enter First Number : <br>
            <input type="text" id="Text1" name="TextBox1">
            <br>
            Enter Second Number : <br>
            <input type="text" id="Text2" name="TextBox2">
            <br>
            Result : <br>
            <input type="text" id="txtresult" name="TextBox3">
            <br>
         <input type="button" name="clickbtn" value="Display Result" onclick="add_number()">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function add_number(){
            var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementsById("Text1").value);
            var second_number = parseInt(document.getElementsById("Text2").value);
            var result = first_number + second_number;
            document.getElementById("txtresult").innerHTML = result;    
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: I assume that you have missed to add a closing `</div>` before the `<script type="text/javascript"`. Correct?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what you assume is not correct. I have checked again but its not working though I have closed the </div>

Comment: This problem was caused by a typo: `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sjh36otu/

```
        function add_number() {

            var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("Text1").value);
            var second_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("Text2").value);
            var result = first_number + second_number;

            document.getElementById("txtresult").value = result;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks much Mikey. Further more I was using Brackets editor to write the code. When I press . after getElementById there is nothing like .value; instead of .value I found .nodeValue. Could you please tell me if there any significant difference in between?

Comment: Yes there is a difference. Here you can find a clear explanation http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/nodeValue and this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875411/javascript-getting-node-value clarifies it a little bit. You probably don't get `.value` in brackets because it is really common to use it so most people don't need a reminder for that.

Answer (score 3):

When you assign your variables "first_number" and "second_number", you need to change "document.getElementsById" to the singular "document.getElementById".

Answer (score 1):

```
var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("Text1").value);
var second_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("Text2").value);

// This is because your method .getElementById has the letter 's': .getElement**s**ById
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

function sum()
{
    var value1= parseInt(document.getElementById("txtfirst").value);
    var value2=parseInt(document.getElementById("txtsecond").value);
    var sum=value1+value2;
    document.getElementById("result").value=sum;

}
 </script>
```

Comment: can you provide more details ?

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple mistake. Don't worry....
Simply use `getElementById` instead `getElementsById`

**true**

```
var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("Text1").value);
```

**False**

```
var first_number = parseInt(document.getElementsById("Text1").value);
```

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.minus = function() {     

     var a = Number($scope.a || 0);
            var b = Number($scope.b || 0);
            $scope.sum1 = a-b;
    // $scope.sum = $scope.sum1+1; 
    alert($scope.sum1);
    }

   $scope.add = function() {     

     var c = Number($scope.c || 0);
            var d = Number($scope.d || 0);
            $scope.sum2 = c+d;
    alert($scope.sum2);
    }
});
```

```html
<head>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <h3>Using Double Negation</h3>

    <p>First Number:
        <input type="text" ng-model="a" />
    </p>
    <p>Second Number:
        <input type="text" ng-model="b" />
    </p>
    <button id="minus" ng-click="minus()">Minus</button>
    <!-- <p>Sum: {{ a - b }}</p>  -->
 <p>Sum: {{ sum1 }}</p>

    <p>First Number:
        <input type="number" ng-model="c" />
    </p>
    <p>Second Number:
        <input type="number" ng-model="d" />
    </p>
 <button id="minus" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    <p>Sum: {{ sum2 }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
var x = y + z;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
<p>
<label>Enter First Number : </label><br>
<input type="number" id="txt1" name="text1"><br/>
<label>Enter Second Number : </label><br>
<input type="number" id="txt2" name="text2">
</p>
<p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
</p>
<br/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `document.getElementById("txtresult").value= result;`

You are setting the value of the textbox to the result. The `id="txtresult"` is not an HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
       var text1 = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
       var text2 = document.getElementById("Text2").value;
       var answer = parseInt(text1) + parseInt(text2);
      function add_number(){
       document.getElementById("txtresult").value = answer;
       }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some description to explain your code.

Answer (score 0):

its Not `document.getElementsById` function its  `document.getElementById` try it

Comment: I know you were trying to help. But this has been motioned multiple times in other answers. Don't waste your time on old questions unless the existing answer is outdated or not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
.innerHTML = result;
```

use

```
.value = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang = "en">              
        <head>  
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Calculator DEMO</title>  
                    
        </head> 
        
    <body> 
                
        <div>

            <p>
                <label>Enter Number 1: </label><br>
                    <input type="number" id="txt1" name="text1"><br/>
                <label>Enter Number 2: </label><br>
                    <input type="number" id="txt2" name="text2">

            </p>

            <p>
                <button onclick="resultsum()">+</button>
            
                <button onclick="resultsub()">-</button>
            
                <button onclick="resultmul()">*</button>
            </p>
            
            <p>
                <button onclick="resultdiv()">/</button>
            
                <button onclick="resultmod()">%</button>
            
                <button onclick="resultper()">percentage</button>
            </p>
        
            <script>
                        
                function resultsum()
                    {  
                        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
                        var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
                        var sm = y + z;
                        document.getElementById("resultsum").innerHTML = sm;
                        
                            if(document.getElementById("resultsum").innerHTML%2!=0)
                            {
                                alert('"calculated Result is odd"');    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('"calculated Result is not "ODD"');
                            }
                    }
                function resultsub()
                    {
                        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
                        var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
                        var sb = y - z;

                        document.getElementById("resultsub").innerHTML = sb;
                            {
                                if(document.getElementById("resultsub").innerHTML%2!=0)
                                {
                                    alert('"calculated Result is odd"');
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alert('"calculated Result is not "ODD"');
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    function resultmul()
                    {  
                        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
                        var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
                        var ml = y * z;
                        document.getElementById("resultmul").innerHTML = ml;
                        
                            if(document.getElementById("resultmul").innerHTML%2!=0)
                            {
                                alert('"calculated Result is odd"');    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('"calculated Result is not "ODD"');
                            }
                    }
                    function resultdiv()
                    {  
                        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
                        var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
                        var dv = y / z;
                        document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML = dv;
                        
                            if(document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML%2!=0)
                            {
                                alert('"calculated Result is odd"');    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('"calculated Result is not "ODD"');
                            }                        
                    }
                    function resultmod()
                    {  
                        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
                        var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
                        var md = y + z;
                        document.getElementById("resultmod").innerHTML = md;
                        
                            if(document.getElementById("resultmod").innerHTML%2!=0)
                            {
                                alert('"calculated Result is odd"');    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('"calculated Result is not "ODD"');
                            }
                        
                    }
                    function resultper()
                    {  
                        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
                        var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
                        var per = (y + z )/2;
                        document.getElementById("resultper").innerHTML = per;
                        
                            if(document.getElementById("resultper").innerHTML%2!=0)
                            {
                                alert('"calculated Result is odd"');    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('"calculated Result is not "ODD"');
                            }
                    }
            </script>
            <input type="text" name="Answers" id="ans" >        
                <br/>
            <p id="resultsum"></p>
            <p id="resultsub"></p>
                    <p id="resultmul"></p>
                    
                    <p id="resultdiv"></p>
                <p id="resultmod"></p>
            <p id="resultper"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply convert the given number using Number primitive type in JavaScript as shown below.

```
var c = Number(first) + Number(second);
```