# How to get a value from an <input> rather than a prompt?

Tags: javascript, html, math, tags, prompt

I’m trying to make a surface area of a cylinder calculator as a beginner project. So far I’ve only used JavaScript to make it and it works fine.

```js
var radius = prompt("What is the radius?");
var height = prompt("What is the height?");

var answer = 6.28*radius*radius+6.28*radius*height;

alert(answer);
```

I am using `prompt` to get the variables but is there any way to use HTML `<input>` tags instead of `prompt`?

Comment: You need to learn about the DOM APIs and events.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: Java is to javascript as Ham is to hamster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a simple form in html. The `onkeyup="calculate()` part, indicates that whenever the `onkeyup` event ocurs, it fires the `calculate()` functiono in javascript.

Then, with javascript (not java!), we calculate. Look the comments on the code:

```js
function calculate(){
var radius = document.getElementById("radius").value; //we get the radius
var height = document.getElementById("height").value; //we get the height

var answer = 6.28*radius*radius+6.28*radius*height; //same line you used before
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer; //we print the answer
}
```

```html
<p>Radius:</p><input id="radius" type="number" onkeyup="calculate()">
<p>Height:</p><input id="height" type="number" onkeyup="calculate()">
<p>Answer:</p><p id="answer">
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two text boxes in html and add a button.

Onclick of button, call a javaScript function which will take the values of the textboxes and calculate the volume.

Similar to [Add two numbers and display result in textbox with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520173/add-two-numbers-and-display-result-in-textbox-with-javascript)

As far I understand from the code, you are doing JavaScript, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with HTML and javascript.
build a form and then use the values.
inside a HTML Body:

```
<form id="area-calculate" onsubmit="calculate()">
  radius: <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="radius">
  height: <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="height">
  <input type="submit" value="calculate">
</form>
<div id="answerPlaceHolder"></div>
<script>
  function calculate(){
    var radius = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var answer = 6.28*radius*radius+6.28*radius*height;
    document.getElementById("answerPlaceHolder").innerHTML = "the answer is: "+answer;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two textfields for input using

```
<input type=“text” id=“tf1”>
<input type=“text” id=“tf2”>
```

Use JavaScript to call a function and inside do

```
var v1=document.getElementById(“tf1”).value
var v2=document.getElementById(“tf2”).value
```

Now variables v1 and v2 has value of text boxes

> Remember call the JavaScript inside the function else it will get
>   empty value as soon as it loads the page.(use onclick on a button)